# How can i create CSS Border like this?

Tags: css

[image]

We have a new project and my company hired a designer. The division in his design uses a bottom border like the image, I can only recreate the dark line using linear gradient, but my worry is the white glow in the center of it. Thanks in advance

Edited 
Here's my current code for the border below (without the glowing section)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .custom-border {
            position: relative;
        }
    
        .custom-border::after {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10px;
            content: '';
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
        }
    
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="custom-border " style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color: #0E1C6F;">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? disclose your previous efforts to solve it

Comment: Please add your sample code as well.

Comment: I think you can easily get a similar result using a `box-shadow` here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/60x9zLyb/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily. I used your example and modified it to get what you need.

Use inset box shadow for the dark gradient by tailoring the positioning, size and spread to move it in your preferred position. See the `box shadow` property for the `custom-border` classed element: the first two values are the *horizontal* and *vertical* positioning, *the third value is the size* and *the fourth is the spread* of the shadow. The fifth element is the color. The main idea is, that the spread should be the same as the size, but in the negative range. This and the negative offset in the vertical positioning makes your "one-sided" shadow.

Then we can create the 'shine' with the `:after` pseudo-element by adding a radial gradient background with an elliptical shape and doubling the background size height. this way we get a half ellipse.

I didn't get the proper colors and sizes, but you can tinker with them to get them right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #0E1C6F;
        }
        .custom-border {
            position: relative;
            /* shifted box shadow (only bottom part visible) */
            box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 10px -10px #000;
            height: 50px; 
            width: 100%; 
            background-color: #0E1C6F;
        }
    
        .custom-border::after {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 15px;
            content: '';
            /* a border line to have that subtle black line */
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse, rgba(0,37,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,37,255,.1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%);
            /*resize the background image to be double height, this crops the lower half of the ellipse and makes it look like a light shine from behind*/
            background-size: 100% 200%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="custom-border">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit rejected because changed the intent and output.